# Play[ ] takes very long to play a custom sound

Tags: sound

I am using

```
Play[f[t], {t,0,30}]
```

to play sound defined by f(t), which is 30 seconds long. It is taking a very long time to evaluate this expression (10 minutes and counting). What are the limitations of Play that might make it take so long?

If it is relevant, my function f(t) is a piecewise sequence of sine waves strung together, each about 2 seconds long.

Comment: How long does this take? `Play[Sin[t], {t, 0, 30}]`

Comment: No time at all...

Comment: Then I suppose interpolating a Table[] of your piecewise fuction should work.

Comment: What do you mean by interpolating a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{Sin[t + 0.2], 2 > t >= 0}, {Sin[t - 0.4], 
     4 >= t >= 2}}];
Plot[f@t, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
int[t_] = Interpolation[Table[{t, f@t}, {t, 0, 4, 0.01}]]@t;
Plot[int@t, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Play[int@t, {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Easier way:

```
Sound[{Play[Sin[t+1], {t, 0, 2}], Play[Sin[t-1], {t, 0, 2}]}]
```